# translatable strings in protected/config/main.php

Tags: php, yii, multilingual

How can I translate strings inside Yii's `protected/config/main.php`?

`__()` configured correctly and works inside `controllers` and `views`. but in config file it dose not work.

I know the reason, `__()` dose not know the target language yet, as it defined here. so how can I make config files translatable?

```
return array(
  ....
  'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
  'name' => __("Sitename"),
  'language' => 'fa_ir',
  ....
```

Comment: In yii translation function is [`Yii::t()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#t-detail) and if you want gettext support use `CGettextMessageSource`. For more info refer [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#translation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use the application at this point, since this is the configuration to actually initialize the app itself. you may change your app name later, after the initialization